# How to get all id from model in django

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
  @api_view(['POST','GET'])
def nric_validate(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ki = Kiosk.objects.all()
        serializer =Kioskserialize(ki, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    if request.method =="POST":
        k = Kiosk.objects.all()
        serializer = Kioskserialize(k, many=True)
        
        
        nric_no = request.POST['nric_no']
        user = auth.authenticate(nric_no=nric_no)
        
        # uid = request.POST.get('uid')
        uid = FRUser.objects.values_list('uid',flat=True)
        print(uid)
        if uid ==  nric_no:
             Kiosk(nric_no=nric_no).save()
             return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my views it shows response error in this views

****models.py****

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app_user_mngmt.models.image import Image
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from .frtemplate import FRTemplate


## Table for saving FRUser details.
class FRUser(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(to=Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    frtemplate = models.ForeignKey(to=FRTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True)
    user_type = models.TextField(null=True)
    uid = models.TextField(null=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    visit_purpose = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    employee_number = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    valid_till_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    valid_from_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    valid_till_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    is_blacklisted = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)    
    is_other_visit_purpose = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

How to get all uid from FRUser model in views
How to do code for to get all uid from FRUser model database
Thanks in advance

Comment: `FRUser.objects.values_list('uid', flat=True)`

Comment: Ok but it shows  this error  ...Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`How to solve this

Comment: What is `nric_no` in your POST data? You compare this against your list of ids, `if uid == nric_no:` which is obviously returning false because POST data will always be a string. What is the logic that you are trying to implement with this data?

Comment: Iam checking this condition for enter to next page nric is model field name
So If uid and nric number is there same only it should enter to next page

Comment: If uid and nric number is same then only it should enter to next page how to compare that and nric number is front end data

Comment: Please help me to solve this